# Определить имеются ли в списке текущих загрузок браузеров Firefox и Internet Explorer активные задания

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, firefox

Как и каким средствами администрирования определить текущий статус запущенного браузера Mozilla Firefox или Internet Explorer? Необходимо перед принудительным завершением процессов браузера проверить, имеется ли в данный момент активная загрузка файла браузером - идет ли скачивание.

Answer (score 0):

Не было желания искать решение с помощью встроенных средств Windows: аудит файлов, встроенная в ОС платформа разработки .Net Framework и пр.
Поэтому решил воспользоваться готовым решением. Тем более файлы у меня скачиваются в один и тот же каталог - папку Downloads в профиле пользователя.

Установил бесплатную утилиту Microsoft [Handle](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/downloads/handle).
Данная утилита может показать, какой процесс открыл файлы и по какому пути.

Настроил простой batch-file, который будет отображать наличие открытых файлов в каталоге загрузки процессом Firefox. Если утилита **handle** не нашла таковых, она выводит строку: `No matching handles`.

```
@echo off
(handle -nobanner -p firefox \Downloads\) |find "No matching handles">NUL
IF  %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 0 echo Download state
```